# Sublime Text 3: проблемы с кодировкой HTML-файлов

Tags: html, кодировка, sublime-text-3

Есть вёрстка в файлах html, которую надо натянуть на cms. Открываю в Notepad++ - всё норм:

```
<div class="sb_event">
    <div class="sb_event_header"><h4>Ближайшие события</h4></div>
    <p><a href="">29 января 2017, Москва</a></p>
    <p>Семинар производителей мебели России и СНГ, Обсуждение тенденций.</p>
</div>
```

Открываю в Sublime Text 3 - вот такая ерунда:

```
<div class="sb_event">
    <div class="sb_event_header"><h4>Áëèæàéøèå ñîáûòèÿ</h4></div>
    <p><a href="">29 àâãóñòà 2017, Ìîñêâà</a></p>
    <p>Ñåìèíàð ïðîèçâîäèòåëåé ìåáåëè Ðîññèè è ÑÍÃ, Îáñóæäåíèå òåíäåíöèé.</p>
</div>
```

Никакие манипуляции с Save with Encoding результата не дают. В чём здесь проблема и как сделать так, чтобы можно было в Sublime работать (Notepad++ как-то не очень мне нравится)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте меню `Preferences -> Settings-User`и между фигурными скобками добавьте строку:

```
"fallback_encoding": "Cyrillic (Windows 1251)",
```

И перезапустите Sublime.

Также можете установить шрифт (убедитесь, что он поддерживает кириллицу):

```
"font_face": "Consolas",
```